# Progress bar within JqueryUi tab

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs, struts2-jquery

Hi I am using Jquery Ui Tabs to generate tabs dynamically . Now on every click i am calling an action through Struts2 and pulling content from database and showing it in tab content. My requirement is until the action completes i need to show a progress or wait bar within the tab content. I am using HTML page for display . Please suggest! Help is appreciated!

Comment: Any help is appreciated ! Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

you can either use the `sj:tab` attributes `indicator` or `loadingText` to achieve this.

For using `indicator`, you need to first place your `progress bar` with assigned `id` within your page and hide it by default. The tab will then show this `progress bar` before the tab content is loaded.

For `loadingText`, the tab simply display the text you set into the tab before the content is loaded.

https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TabTag